# Why does alphavantage return volume zero and wrong prices

Tags: alpha-vantage

I'm trying to use what seems like a great idea but some of the prices and volumes are wrong:

Example:

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=SMT.LON&apikey=mykey&datatype=json

As you can see below the result for 2019-08-05 has a volume of zero and the prices are 2 orders of magnitude smaller. There are more examples of the same thing happening further on.  This means the api can't be used for analysis.  Is there any reason why these values are appearing?

```
{
"Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Daily Time Series with Splits and Dividend Events",
    "2. Symbol": "SMT.LON",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2019-08-07",
    "4. Output Size": "Compact",
    "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
},
"Time Series (Daily)": {
    "2019-08-07": {
        "1. open": "521.0000",
        "2. high": "530.0000",
        "3. low": "519.5000",
        "4. close": "522.1314",
        "5. adjusted close": "522.1314",
        "6. volume": "1259995",
        "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
        "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
    },
    "2019-08-06": {
        "1. open": "516.5000",
        "2. high": "525.9450",
        "3. low": "513.0000",
        "4. close": "518.0000",
        "5. adjusted close": "518.0000",
        "6. volume": "3353161",
        "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
        "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
    },
    "2019-08-05": {
        "1. open": "5.2430",
        "2. high": "5.2430",
        "3. low": "5.2430",
        "4. close": "5.2430",
        "5. adjusted close": "5.2430",
        "6. volume": "0",
        "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
        "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
    },
    "2019-08-02": {
        "1. open": "5.3989",
        "2. high": "5.3989",
        "3. low": "5.3989",
        "4. close": "5.3989",
        "5. adjusted close": "5.3989",
        "6. volume": "0",
        "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
        "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
    },
    "2019-08-01": {
        "1. open": "558.0000",
        "2. high": "568.5000",
        "3. low": "557.0000",
        "4. close": "568.5000",
        "5. adjusted close": "568.5000",
        "6. volume": "2141407",
        "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
        "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
    },
    "2019-07-31": {
        "1. open": "562.5000",
        "2. high": "565.5000",
        "3. low": "560.0580",
        "4. close": "563.0000",
        "5. adjusted close": "563.0000",
        "6. volume": "1519041",
        "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
        "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
    },
    "2019-07-30": {
        "1. open": "5.5441",
        "2. high": "5.5441",
        "3. low": "5.5441",
        "4. close": "5.5441",
        "5. adjusted close": "5.5441",
        "6. volume": "0",
        "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
        "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
    },
    "2019-07-29": {
        "1. open": "5.5449",
        "2. high": "5.5449",
        "3. low": "5.5449",
        "4. close": "5.5449",
        "5. adjusted close": "5.5449",
        "6. volume": "0",
        "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
        "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
    },
```

Comment: Did you resolve this? Were you able to conduct meaningful analysis using this data?

Comment: No, I had to use a different data source in the end.